# Помощь с запросом SQL

Tags: sql

Есть задача - посчитать количество клиентов, которые сделали заказы в разных магазинах в пределах одного домена.
Есть 3 таблицы:
`orders` , в которой - `remote_id` (уникальный номер заказа) , `shop_code` (код магазина), `user_id` (может содержать `NULL`) и `phone` (номер клиента)
`shops`, в которой - `code` (код магазина), `city_code` 
`domains`, в которой `domain` и `city_code`
Остальные данные отбросил за ненадобностью.

```
oreders:       
remote_id | shop_code | user_id | phone

shops:   
code | city_code

domains:
domain | city_code
```

Я составил такой запрос

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT orders.phone) 
FROM orders
INNER JOIN shops ON shop_code = code
INNER JOIN domains ON shops.city_code = domains.city_code
WHERE orders.phone IN (
          SELECT phone 
          FROM orders 
          GROUP BY phone 
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      );
```

Но он не совсем корректно считает (учитывает клиентов, которые сделали больше одного заказа, но в одном магазине. Нужно, чтобы считало только тех, кто в разных магазинах).

Comment: Замените словесное описание структуры на CREATE TABLE таблиц. Покажите пример наполнения таблиц (в виде INSERT INTO) и требуемый результат ДЛЯ ЭТИХ ДАННЫХ.

Comment: *посчитать количество клиентов, которые сделали заказы в разных магазинах в пределах одного домена.* Это ДВА уровня группировки, на каждом надо выполнять подсчёты. Так что CTE либо подзапросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Схематично

```sql
SELECT домен, COUNT(юзер) AS количество
FROM ( SELECT юзер, домен
       FROM связанные таблицы данных
       GROUP BY юзер, домен
       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT магазин) > 1 ) AS подзапрос
GROUP BY домен
```

Если нужно просто такое количество, а не с разблюдовкой по доменам, то

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT юзер) AS количество
FROM ( SELECT юзер, домен
       FROM связанные таблицы данных
       GROUP BY юзер, домен
       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT магазин) > 1 ) AS подзапрос
```